# Variable de una comparación de un array de objetos me retorna datos undefined

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función donde comparo dos `array` de objetos, el detalle es que en consola checando el resultado me imprime dos veces la primera bien **y ya luego me imprime el mismo `array` de objetos pero como los campos `undefined`.** No sé por qué me lo imprime así.

```
    jsonodsunicosparametros = [
      {id: undefined, id_ods_meta: 3, activo: true}
      {id: undefined, id_ods_meta: 4, activo: true}
    ]

    jsonods_modificar = [
      {id: 6, id_ods_meta: 1, activo: true}
      {id: 7, id_ods_meta: 2, activo: true}
    ]

    const mergeods = (odsA, odsB) => odsA.map((pA) => ({
         ...pA,
         activo: odsB.some((pB) => pB.id_ods_meta === pA.id_ods_meta ),
    }));
    const mergedods = mergeods(jsonodsunicosparametros, jsonods_modificar);
    console.log(mergedods)
```

y me lo imprime en consola así. Quiero que me guarde el primer resultado, pero al final me guarda el resultado del último impresión de consola:

```
    //primera impresion en consola
    {id: 6, id_ods_meta: 1, activo: false}
    {id: 7, id_ods_meta: 2, activo: false}

    //segunda impresion en consola
    {id: undefined, id_ods_meta: undefined, activo: false}
    {id: undefined, id_ods_meta: undefined, activo: false}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya lo resolví, lo tenía dentro de un for, entonces como era el número de registros que selecciona el usuario, si en este caso seleccionaba dos, pues dos veces me iteraba mi función, si elegía n cantidad n cantidad de veces se iba a ejecutar la función.